# check if a non-clustered index exists on a table column

Tags: sql-server, indexing

In SQL Server 2000, how do I check if a non-clustered index exists on a single column of table?

Answer (score 5):

You look it up in [sysindexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260413(SQL.80).aspx) and [sysindexkeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260412(SQL.80).aspx). You can also use sp_help to explain a table, including all indexes.

```
select k.*, x.name
from  sysindexes x 
join sysindexkeys k on k.id = x.id
join syscolumns c on c.id = x.id and k.colid=c.colid
where x.id = object_id('yourtable')
and c.name='yourcolumn'
and x.indid > 1
```

You can tell from the k.keyno column the position of key in the index, if is not 1 then the column is probably SARGable only if combined with other columns that are ahead of it in the index key order.

Comment: I changed from master to mydb. I see a lot of strange names and column names. I don't understand any of it. I only want to see if a column named "Person" or "ID" has been indexed or not. How do I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the "sysindexes" view... I'm on a mac now so I can't give you the exact, tested query..

```
SELECT * FROM sysindexes
```

Answer (score 0):

check the "type" column (for value<>1, that means not clustered) of sys.indexes table
type_desc specifies CLUSTERED, NONCLUSTERED or HEAP

Comment: hey, who edited my answer? It's MS SQL Server 2000, there is NO sys.indexes!